# Reduce space between barchart and x-axis

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

I'm using [charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in iOS to draw bar chart. But in the bar chart that I'm getting, some whitespace occurs between the bottom of the bars and the x-axis. How can I reduce or eliminate this ?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue is reported [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/804).

Following is the fix.

```
barChartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
```

Comment: Been looking for this answer for hours. Thanks!